# API call causes page reload

Tags: javascript, fetch, page-refresh

I'm using JS to make API calls in my HTML website.
But the page is refresh with DELETE method

```
    async function delete(param) {
        const response = await fetch(`${api_Url}/products${param}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`
            },
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
    };
```

Response :

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers : heders {}
ok: true
redirect: false
state: 204
statusText : « No content »
type: « CORS »
url : « http://localhost:5678/api/products/9 »
[[Prototype]] : response
```

And after the request, the page is refreshed

This function is called by this code :

```
    const deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.delete_icon');

    deleteBtn.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', event => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const Id = event.currentTarget.id;
            delete(Id);
        });
    });
```

But this code is not the reason for the refresh.
One thing worked :

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = '';
});
```

But there is a popup
(I can't use package and library)

And it is only the Delete API call that causes this refresh because from the console by calling delete(1), the page is refreshed

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: `fetch` will not cause a page reload, so there's something *else* going on. You're already cancelling the default action of the click, so it's not the obvious thing. Please update the question with a full [mre] -- an HTML file with the necessary elements and code in it that we can run locally to replicate the problem (since there appear to be forms involved, sadly you probably can't make it a Stack Snippet).

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue use:  `async/await`. First,return the promise from the **fetch request** and then use **await** to wait for the request to complete before calling the `event.preventDefault()`

Issue is in you code is: the **fetch**  request is async , so before completes the request page is refreshed

```
 async function deleteProduct(param) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const response = await fetch(`${api_Url}/products${param}`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`
        },
      });
      console.log(response);
    }
```

click event listner is like this

```
element.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    const Id = event.currentTarget.id;
    await deleteProduct(Id);
});
```

Try this